# Thunderbird is missing local folders structure even though they exist in ~/.thunderbird

Tags: thunderbird

My imap and pop structures are correct and so it is clear that I have the correct profile. The data structure is found in
~/.thunderbird/sc3dr5b5.default/Mail/Local\ Folders/. for example in this directory there file for Business, Business.msf and a directory Business.sbd.
And indeed that directory contains a file for each business for which I save mail.
The problem is they do not show up in the thunderbird application. In Local Folders I see only Sent, Trash and Outbox.

Answer (score 0):

The directory on Local\ Folders was incorrect, it pointed to a folder below this level. correcting that solved my problem.